# Component Fails To Re-Render Correctly Using setState Hook

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am teaching myself to React. I have created a little project to familiarise myself with React. I basically want the slider to adjust the grid size below. However, when changing the slider, it re-renders completely incorrectly. What it should do is create a square grid, with the dimensions equal to the slider value. The grid should always be square, and as the slider value changes, so should the height and width of the square.

The right-hand side column should have 1 column, but as many rows as the square on the left. Right now it does not grow or shrink with the slider. Any changes to the slider value just create 2 squares, with no relation to the slider value.

Before:

[image: Before image]

After:

[image: After image]

Here is what the code looks like (simply paste into App.js after running NPX-create-react-app). If someone could explain how I can get this to work as intended it would be appreciated:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class Matrix {
  constructor(rows, cols) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.cols = cols;
    this.size = rows * cols;
    this.values = new Array(this.size).fill("");
  }
}

function Cell(props) {
  return (
    <input
      className="matrix-component"
      id={props.id}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={(e) => props.onChange(props.id, e.target.value)}
    ></input>
  );
}

function App() {
  let [dim, setDim] = useState(3);
  let [matrix, setMatrix] = useState(new Matrix(dim, dim));
  let [rhs, setRHS] = useState(new Matrix(dim, 1));

  function updateMatrix(i, value) {
    let new_values = matrix.values.slice();
    let new_matrix = new Matrix(matrix.rows, matrix.cols);
    new_values[i] = value;
    new_matrix.values = new_values;
    setMatrix(new_matrix);
  }

  function updateRHS(i, value) {
    let index = i.replace(/\D/g, "");
    let new_values = rhs.values.slice();
    let new_matrix = new Matrix(matrix.rows, 1);
    new_values[index] = value;
    new_matrix.values = new_values;
    setRHS(new_matrix);
  }

  function updateSlider(value) {
    setDim(value);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    console.log(matrix.values);
    console.log(rhs.values);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="content">
        <div className="matrix">
          <div>
            {Array.apply(null, Array(dim)).map(function (x, i) {
              const col = Array.apply(null, Array(dim)).map(function (y, j) {
                return (
                  <Cell
                    key={i * dim + j}
                    id={i * dim + j}
                    value={matrix.values[i * dim + j]}
                    onChange={updateMatrix}
                  />
                );
              });
              return <div key={i}>{col}</div>;
            })}
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="rhs">
              {Array.apply(null, Array(dim)).map(function (x, i) {
                return (
                  <Cell
                    key={"rhs" + i}
                    id={"rhs" + i}
                    value={rhs.values[i]}
                    onChange={updateRHS}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button onClick={handleClick}>Solve</button>
      </div>

      <input
        type="range"
        min="3"
        max="10"
        value={dim}
        onChange={(event) => updateSlider(event.target.value)}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  /* background: grey; */
}

.matrix {
  /* float: left; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.matrix-component {
  border-width: thin;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.rhs {
  margin-left: 40px;
  display: grid;
}
```

Comment: Does your code throw errors? I'm pretty sure the HTML segments in your JS should be strings.

Comment: Nope, no errors thrown by the code. Even when changing the slider it seems to work, but not render properly.

Comment: Do you know where to look to see if any errors are thrown? I'm pretty sure your code should be throwing errors... unless you made a lot of changes when you copied it to stackOverflow...

Comment: I am looking at the developer console in Chrome, it doesn't seem to show any errors - I'll post a screenshot to the original post.

Comment: What do "Fails" and "Re-Render Correctly" and "it re-renders completely incorrectly" and "work as intended" mean? It's not clear from the image or question what the issue is. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added some more details, but basically the slider value should control the size of the grid and column on the right. If the value is 2, then the square should be 2x2, and the column on the right should be 2 squares high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function updateSlider(value) {
    setDim(value);
  }
```

The `event.target.value` is a string, so you switch `dim` from an integer to a string. If you convert `value` into an integer it'll work correctly.

```
  function updateSlider(value) {
    setDim(parseInt(value, 10));
  }
```

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you dammit I see now. Would upvote and accept but my rank is too low.

Comment: No worries! Glad to help!